# Как посчитать количество записей в таблицах?

Tags: php, mysql

Я знаю, что есть запросы типа:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM teble WHERE field = "U"
```

Но мне необходимо подсчитать общее количество записей в сорока таблицах. Можно конечно в цикле выполнить 40 запросов и результат сложить, но возможно есть более красивое решение?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если надо посчитать количество значений тупо всех таблиц...

```
// .... подключение

$res = mysql_query('SHOW TABLES');
//выберем все таблицы нашей базу

while($row = mysql_fetch_row($res)) {
    //сложим подзапросы для подсчета всех табличек в массив
    $queryArray[] = '(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' . $row[0] . ')';
}

// сфоримруем наш запрос...
$countQuery = implode(' + ', $queryArray);

// AS total укажем для красивого результата в mysql_fetch_assoc
$query .= 'SELECT (' . $countQuery . ') AS total';

$res = mysql_query($query);
$res = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);

// на выходе - колличество записей всех таблиц произвольной БД 
echo $res['total'];
```

Кому надо будет без труда переделает сей код под подсчет определенных значений в 1ом запросе..

Вообще в реальной разработке я бы сделал вьюшку и не парился :)

Comment: Вьюхи раньше не делал, можно поподробнее про это, какие плюсы?

Comment: Ну во первых - создавая VIEW запрос автоматически кешируется, во вторых - описав VIEW в php коде вы делаете запрос вида `"SELECT * FROM viewName"`, что по определению намного приятнее и удобнее...<br> по поводу производительности моего варианта и варианта <b>Виталий Кустов'a</b> - вы разницу не ощутите вообще, выбирайте любой :)<br>
VIEW идеальное решение если вы уверены в том что вам не надо будет часто лезть и менять ее, т.е. например вам сейчас надо подсчитать каких то 50 таблиц - вы раз написали и пользуетесь, если же нет - строго php кодом, про скорость предложеных я уже написал выше...

Comment: В моем случае я заранее не знаю сколько таблиц, и какие таблицы мне нужно будет подсчитать, поэтому VIEW в данной ситуации не подойдет.

Answer (score 2):

```
select sum(cnt) as cnt 
from 
(SELECT count(*) as cnt FROM tab1 
UNION ALL 
SELECT count(*) as cnt FROM tab2 
UNION ALL 
SELECT count(*) as cnt FROM tab3
) as t
```

Держите)

Comment: Тоже думал над таким вариантом, и над вариантом который ниже. Вопрос в том какой из вариантом будет более производительный?